# Delta Kossel 3d Printer Heatsink issues

Tags: delta, heat-management, kossel

I feel stupid for asking, but could it cause issues if the Heat sink/Heater block/Extruder tip can spin freely in a Kossel Delta 3d printer? I went to remove the extruder tip the other day, and noticed that all of the assembly is free spinning. I am new to the 3d printing community.

**Clarification:**

It's the whole assembly rotating as a single piece. The heater block, heat break/sink and extruder tip are all rotating together, in the effector.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as being unsuitable to your question.

Answer (score 2):

When assembling the hot end tip, make sure you screw in the extruder tip to the aluminum block first, then screw that assembly to the heat sink fins. On my Kossel, I did it the other way around, and had very poor results.

If the whole assembly is spinning, then the clamp screws are either too long and can't tighten properly, or the holes might be stripped, or they're just not tight.

And yes, any movement in the hot end can cause problems, since we're dealing with steps as small as .1 mm.